# How can I get workout record from the Activity app in the iphone, does the apple sdk supply this API?

Tags: ios, watchkit, watch, watchos-2

I want to get the workout record data from the Activity app in my iphone, does the apple sdk supply this API to access it? Thanks!

The detail data I want to access is as below screen:

[image]

Comment: Googling `ios watchkit get workout from activity app` seems to yield a number of results?

Comment: But I can not find the usefully message to me about this question? Do you find the solution to this problem, if you find ,could you give me the web link?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to all of this data using the HealthKit API. I recommend starting with [HKHealthStore](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/index.html) and the WWDC videos about HealthKit.

Comment: Do you mean I used splitTotalEnergy this Api to get the details data of activity app, but I can not find any samples from the apple document.

Comment: Do all of this data only access by apple watch? From the document of the app developer, I find workout session feature, but the api supplied is only to starting/stopping workout session, but not supply api to access work session data? Ths!

Comment: All of this data from the apple watch gets synced to the iPhone. That is how you can see this data on the workout app on the iPhone. HealthKit is really a database and apple provides methods to query any datatype that is added to it. This is where the Apple watch stores all of its health data. Take a look at the health kit WWDC video here to learn more about how to query the data: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-203/

Comment: Thanks lehn0058! I have find the solution to solve this problem, your answer is right, we can use the HealthKit Api to share workout data. After your Iphone  pairs the apple watch, the data from the watch will synchronize the data to the Iphone, so you can get the workout data from the healthy app through using the HealthKit API. Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi，Lehn0058，I have find another problem, I can get workout data through the HealthKit Api except Avg Heart Rate as the screen above, does this data not save in healthy app? If not directly save this value, I only get all of the heart rate value to calculate the average value.

Comment: Average heart rate is not stored in HealthKit, but heart rate is taken every few seconds. You can take all of the heart rate values during the workout to calculate the average heart rate. Look into using HKStatisticsQuery, as healthKit can do some averaging for you without you needing to retrieve all of the data from the heath store.